# Fbml Appllication - Select friend and Post a news on friend's wall - New method

Tags: php, json, facebook, fbml, fbjs

I'm a newbie facebok developer from Italy Sorry, but my english is very poor.
I would like to ask you how to create in my facebook application  a multi-friend selector to allow my users to post news on friend's wall.
How can I let my user select friends, and than send to those friends a news on their wall?
I 'don't know ajax, so please can you just suggest me something that I can do?
I notice that facebook has changed the way to do this thing.
I'm using fbml. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a facebook app in the [Facebook Apps](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) , then they will provide u one secret key as well as app id, using this you can connect with facebook.
To access your friends data , they need to add your facebook application .
If you know [PHP](http://www.php.net) then you can use the [Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk)  to do these things using ur app credits.Otherwise u can use fbxml, javascript....

Answer (score 0):

step 1: Create a facebook application by using https://developers.facebook.com/apps

step 2: Run the app with the help heroku (optional)

step 3: This is the link for Graph API Explorer
        https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me select the fields
        that you need.

step 4: **@user.put_wall_post("Hey, Welcome to the Web Application!!!!", {:name => "..."},

        "id_of_your_friend")** is used to post on your friends wall among your selected friends in access token

step 5: By implementing this code on your file your app can access to post on your friends's
        wall